# Как прибавить рабочие дни к дате с помощью JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, дата

Всем доброго времени суток.
Стоит задача из выпадающего списка выбрать количество рабочих дней (1/3/5/7/10/15/20/30/40../90) и прибавить их к дате указанной в input:date. Не могу найти никак решение, может есть готовые плагины, или может вообще на PHP можно это реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739059/add-working-days-to-a-date-using-javascript/40739060#40739060

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499944/add-subtract-business-days-in-javascript

Comment: вы под рабочими днями имеете в виду пн-пт  или согласно производственному календарю ?

Comment: @teran да все верно

Comment: " - вам кофе или чай?  - да"

Comment: Извиняюсь, рабочие дни пн-пт